# SQLITE delete taking very long time

Tags: sqlite, orm

I have a table that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE records (
    batchID TEXT,
    A       TEXT,
    A_id    REAL,
    B       TEXT,
    B_id    REAL,
    C       REAL,
    D       REAL,
    E       REAL,
    F       REAL,
    G       REAL,
    H       REAL,
    color   REAL,
    repair  REAL,
    data    BLOB,
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
)
```

I have an index on the table on some of the columns.
Since integrity is not a concern, I have:

```
PRAGMA synchronous = "0"
PRAGMA journal_mode = "OFF"
```

The db has frequent inserts, I have about 2 Million rows in my records table, and the db file size is ~2GB.
Once in a few hours I need to delete 200K rows from the records table. I am using node js orm:

```
db.driver.execQuery('DELETE FROM records WHERE A IN ? AND batchID = ?',
    [['a1', 'a2'], 'batch123'],
    function(err) {
    // do stuff here    
    });
```

In the beginning the delete takes about ~10 seconds, however, after a month of running, the delete statement can take over an hour (!) (see attached performance graph from logs where I log the delete time - the orange circles, the blue circles are node's memory).
This is a problem since at the time of deletion new write request are are generated in node. These write requests are getting queued in memory to a point node uses a huge amount of memory. (since the delete locks the table and blocks the writes)

I suspect this is because the db is getting fragmented.
Vacuum is not an option for me, since this is a product that can't be stopped, and when I tested the vacuum time on a copy of the sqlite db file it took 15 - 30 minutes.
Auto vacuum from my understanding would not help since it does not compact the data in the pages, and can worsen fragmentation.
I also tried to set the page size to 4096, that did not help either.[performance graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgiAB.png)

Comment: Are you sure the deletions are happening with the second one?

Comment: Sorry I had to edit my question, sorry if your comment does not look relevant.

Comment: It is really a different question now :-). I edited it changing only the formatting of the table. You mention that you have some indexes. Which ones? Knowing this is important. Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it gives good suggestions on how to write a question.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a SQLite insert or delete executes within an implicit transaction, thus the slowness.

From https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html:

> A read transaction is started by a SELECT statement, and a write transaction is started by statements like CREATE, DELETE, DROP, INSERT, or UPDATE (collectively "write statements").

From FAQ 19 https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html:

> INSERT is really slow - I can only do few dozen INSERTs per second
>
> By default, each INSERT statement is its own transaction. But if you surround multiple INSERT statements with BEGIN...COMMIT then all the inserts are grouped into a single transaction. The time needed to commit the transaction is amortized over all the enclosed insert statements and so the time per insert statement is greatly reduced.

EDIT: the question has changed after I wrote this answer, so it might seems not to make sense.

Normally you should not use AUTOINCREMENT with SQLite, it is not needed and has adverse performance impact, see https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html:

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.
>
> In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed integer.
>
> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is used.
>
> If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it - so how adding a transaction around the delete makes it faster if it is already executed within an implicit transaction?

Comment: If you have N delete in a loop (which is what I understood was your situation),
if you execute them within an explicit transaction, when a single delete is
executed, it will detect that it is running within an existing transaction and
will not create another one. Thus, there will be only 1 transaction instead of
N. When a transaction is committed, by default the database is synched to disk,
thus the slowness. Is it clearer?

Comment: Sorry I had to edit my question, and I was not deleting in a loop just doing a 'delete' where'